# Redirect duplicate urls in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have a big list of duplicate urls and i need to do some redirect

Example

```
www.mysite.com/mypage/name2_68.html   
www.mysite.com/jjj/name2_68.html   
www.mysite.com/aa/name2_68.html   
www.mysite.com/5654/name2_68.html   

www.mysite.com/mypage/myname87.html   
www.mysite.com/6584/myname87.html   
www.mysite.com/any-number/myname87.html   
www.mysite.com/any_word/myname87.html
```

All i need to do is to redirect them to

```
www.mysite.com/mypage/myname87.html   
www.mysite.com/mypage/name2_68.html
```

So all url with

```
www.mysite.com/anycharactere/example1.html
```

Will be redirect to

```
www.mysite.com/mypage/example1.html
```

Comment: In what ways are your current rewrite statements failing to meet your requirements? Will you post those statements?

Comment: hi i dont know iam still a noob sorry

Comment: You will need to read the mod_rewrite documentation to gain a basic understanding of the process. Feel free to ask here when you have written some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mypage/?
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*\.html?)$ /mypage/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ty for your answer i think it's work but there is a big problem when i add this rule to my htaccess all my site images and text change somthing goes bad with this code

Comment: Change as in? Could you view source and let me know of your findings? .htaccess by itself cannot tamper with your files. It can simply route to a different URL. That's all.

Comment: Ah, I got it. I hadn't restricted the rule to just htm/html files. It should work fine now. Please, check the update. Apologies for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*/([^/]+.html)$ /mypage/$1
```

Comment: ty for the answer but it doesnt work i tried but the urls doesnt redirect

Comment: @BerrKamal Tested on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/. Try to add `RewriteBase /` before `RewriteRule`

Comment: This would lead to an infinite redirection because of the `.*`. The online simulators are only showing you one single pass through your rules. Please, have a look at my answer for reference.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Ok, my bad. Just forgot that /mypage/example1.html matches too. Thanks